# Properties of a strange function

Tags: real-analysis, functions

Def: $$f(x)=0,\ x\neq 0$$
$$f(x)=\lim_{a\to\infty}\frac 1a, f(x)\neq 0, \ x=0 $$

Is $f(x)$ a legal function? Is $f(x)$ continuous and differentiable?

Comment: You should find $f(0)$ yourself.

Comment: It's legal.  But it's the constant function f (x)=0.  A function is determined by its values; not by how we choose to describe it.

Comment: That's not a well defined function.  You have not defined what f (0) is.  Just that it isn't 0.  This *is* continuous if 0 is *not* in the domain and f (0 is not defined.  But if f (0) is something other than 0, f is not continuous.

Comment: Edit completed/ Thank you.......

Comment: $f(x)=1-\frac xx$ has the required properties, it is not continuous but it is differentiable.

Comment: You really shouldn't make an edit that greatly changes the meaning of the question you posted; you should ask your new question in a separate post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Continuity of a function *at a point* is when the limit of the function approaching that point is equal to the value of the function at that point. For $x \neq 0$, the function is continuous - however you approach $x$, the limit will be 0, same as $f(x)$. However, for $x = 0$, you have specifically defined the function in a way that it cannot be continuous. Since the function has a discontinuity, it is not *everywhere continuous*.

Differentiability of a function is similarly defined at individual points, and again your function is differentiable for any $x \neq 0$. But again, your function is not differentiable at $x = 0$, so it is not *everywhere differentiable*.

That said, for many purposes, a mathematician could work in $\mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\}$ and then treat the function as continuous and differentiable with no problem.

EDIT BASED ON LATEST QUESTION EDIT:

Your latest definition of the function is (copied for posterity): $$f(x)=0,\ x\neq 0$$
$$f(x)=\lim_{a\to\infty}\frac 1a,\ x=0 $$

But you have literally just defined a function that is zero everywhere. The limit that you are using to define $f(0)$ is one that is *exactly* equal to zero, by any meaningful interpretation of limits.

Comment: "you have specifically defined the function in a way that it cannot be continuous"  I am going to quibble.  The function has not been defined at x= 0 at all.  As such there is nothing to indicate that $f$ has all of $\mathbb R$ as its domain.  As a function $f: (-\infty, 0)\cap (0, \infty) \rightarrow \{0\}$ so that $f(x) = 0$ for all $x\in  (-\infty, 0)\cap (0, \infty)$ and $0$ simply not in the domain at all, then $f$ indeed *is* continuous for all points that *ARE* in its domain.  ... But that is a quibble.

Comment: I suppose it depends on whether $f(x) \neq 0$ implies that $f(x)$ has a value at all. But yes, it's a quibble. And it doesn't matter, because OP has changed what the question actually is, anyway.

Comment: She changed it back?  Okay.  yeah.  It's ambiguous.  But if you you specify f (x) *doesn't equal something, it's not complete unless you indicate what it *does* equal.  Or at least that it equals something.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. Since
$$\lim_{a\to\infty} \frac{1}{a}=0$$
we have that
$$f(x)=0$$
for all values of $x$. Since $f(x)$ is a constant function, it is both continuous and differentiable.

Answer (score 2):

Since $\lim_{a \to \infty} 1/a = 0$, your function is simply $0$ for all $x$.

Answer (score 2):

A function is determined by its values.  It can be *described* by a human being any way one likes.  This function is nothing more or less than the constant function $f (x)=0$.  You described it in an obtuse (but legitimate) way.  But basically it is the constant function.

It is continuous and differentiable.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely not continuous, since $\lim_{x \to 0} f(x) = \lim_{x \to 0} 0 =0$. Since differentiability implies continuity, it also can't be differentiable.

Comment: Huh.  Definitely *is* continuous.  lim f (x)= lim 0=0 =f (0) so this is compatible with being continuous.

Comment: Ugh.  Sorry.  The question was changed.

Answer (score 0):

Always use the definitions. If $f(0)\ne 0$ and $f(x)=0$ for all $x\ne 0,$ does $f(x$) satisfy the necessary criterion for continuity at $x=0$? No.

Comment: But f (0) *does* equal 0.  So yes it does satisfy the nescessary condition.

Comment: Argh.  The question was changed.  Sorry.

Comment: June 13/17.Fleablood: If it is your -1 vote then would you do me the courtesy of undoing it?  I see another answer that doesn't match the Q, which was clearly not just amended, but completely changed.

Comment: Can you do a "dummy" edit.  I can't seem to upvote unless the answer gets editted.  You are right.  Your answer is correct for how the question is *now* worded.